# Gnus does not delete expired articles

Tags: email, emacs, gnus

I am trying to use emacs gnus to read my mail.

I have read in the documentation (emacs info) that the way to clear away the mail messages is:

1. Mark them as expireable (E)
2. Expire mail articles (with B e in group buffer or other commands)

However, when i do that, no expireable article is marked as deleted (G), and they are not removed from mailbox as well

Note: B  works, but it  is cumbersome for deleting a lot of articles at once.

What could be the reason for that behaviour? What should i check?

Answer (score 1):

Besides having the E mark, the article needs to be older than nnmail-expiry-wait days, which by default is 7, in other words, it has to be older than a week.

Comment: This! I set the `nnmail-expiry-wait` to 1, and now things are working better. I'll likely set it to `immediate` later on.